# How to add a MongoDB-specific query using mongo-spark connector?

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, mongodb-query, apache-spark-sql

i am using "**mongo-spark**" in order to read mongodb from spark 2.0 application.
(https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-spark)

Here is a code example:

```
val readConfig: ReadConfig = ReadConfig(Map(
      "spark.mongodb.input.uri"-> "mongodb://mongodb01.blabla.com/xqwer",
      "collection" -> "some_collection"), 
None)

sparkSession.read.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql").options(readConfig.asOptions).load()
```

does anyone know how to add mongodb query (e.g. "find({ uid: 'ZesSZY3Ch0k8nQtQUIfH' })" ) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `filter()` on `df`

```
val df = sparkSession.read.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql")
                        .options(readConfig.asOptions).load()
df.filter($"uid".equalTo(lit("ZesSZY3Ch0k8nQtQUIfH"))).show()
```

Comment: It'd be very nice if you could add `df.explain(true)` to your answer to see if the comparison is pushed down. Even cooler would be to see the logs of MongoDB with the physical query.

Comment: @mrsrinivas, isn't the "filter" will run on the spark side, and not on the mongodb side ?

Comment: @EranM: I don't have mongodb installed in my system. can you run this `df.filter($"uid".equalTo(lit("ZesSZY3Ch0k8nQtQUIfH"))).explain(true)`. you could see the query plan with pushed filters as @Jacek suggested.

Comment: here is the explain results:

Comment: 2016-12-27 16:01:30,799 INFO  [main] sql.MongoRelation (LoggingTrait.scala:logInfo(48)) - requiredColumns: verticalId, vv, filters: IsNotNull(uid), EqualTo(uid,ZesSZY3Ch0k8nQtQUIfH)
== Parsed Logical Plan ==
'Filter ('uid = ZesSZY3Ch0k8nQtQUIfH)
+- Relation[_browser#0,_city#1,_country#2,_global_visitor_key#3,mtraffic_uuid#23,... 18 more fields] MongoRelation(MongoRDD[0] at RDD at MongoRDD.scala:52,Some(StructType(StructField(_browser,StringType,true), StructField(verticalId,StringType,true), StructField(vv,StringType,true))))

Comment: == Analyzed Logical Plan ==
_browser: string, 
... 18 more fields
Filter (uid#38 = ZesSZY3Ch0k8nQtQUIfH)
+- Relation[_browser#0,,... 18 more fields] MongoRelation(MongoRDD[0] at RDD at MongoRDD.scala:52,Some(StructType(StructField(_browser...

Comment: == Optimized Logical Plan ==
Filter (isnotnull(uid#38) && (uid#38 = ZesSZY3Ch0k8nQtQUIfH))
+- Relation[_browser#0,_city#1,_country#2,_global_visitor_... 18 more fields] MongoRelation(MongoRDD[0] at RDD at MongoRDD.scala:52,Some(StructType(StructField(_browser,StringType,true))))

Comment: == Physical Plan ==
*Filter (isnotnull(uid#38) && (uid#38 = ZesSZY3Ch0k8nQtQUIfH))
+- *Scan MongoRelation(MongoRDD[0] at RDD at MongoRDD.scala:52,Some(StructType(StructField(_browser,StringType,true), StructField(vv,StringType,true)))) [_browser#0,_city#1,_country#2,... 18 more fields] PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(uid), EqualTo(uid,ZesSZY3Ch0k8nQtQUIfH)], ReadSchema: struct<_browser:string,_city:string,_country:string,_global_visitor_key:string,_id:struct<oid:str...

Comment: check pushed filters ( PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(uid), equalTo(uid,ZesSZY3Ch0k8nQtQUIfH)] ) in  **Physical Plan** these filters will be processed at datasouce(mongodb) level.

Comment: @mrsrinivas as i understand from you form the "explain", the query is on the mongodb side. how will look a query on the spark side ?

Comment: Now, Spark DataFrame (`df`) will hold only the documents which are `equalTo(uid,ZesSZY3Ch0k8nQtQUIfH)` rather than loading entire collection and filtering at spark side. you can other spark actions and transformations on it.